# Use AVERAGEIF to average by class number updating across groups in excel

Tags: excel

I have groups which are assigned a number and have a score per row.

How do I set a flexible AVERAGEIF condition so that for each group number it finds the average of the group with the same number. Groups will have different sizes.

[image: Excel example]

How do I fill in the class average?

Comment: Not sure if this is really as simple as it seems or if I am misinterpreting your question. Let me know if the below solution does not work out for you

Answer (score 1):

### Formula

Sounds like you answered your own question but use the below equation and fill down....

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, A2, B:B)
```

---

### Pivot Table

I would go for the pivot table to avoid repeating values. In photo, `Column C` is generated by the above equation. The pivot table and set up are to the right. Although they both provide the same class average, the pivot table neatly summarizes your data.

To implement, highlight your data columns, Insert Pivot, apply the filters you see on the right and make sure your `Score` field is summarized by `Average`

[image]

Comment: **Forgot to turn off grand total field in pivot** - This (79) represents the overall average for all classes!